# How to wrap an asynchronous method that takes a block and turn it synchronous in Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, multithreading, asynchronous, grand-central-dispatch

I want to wrap an async API that look like this:

```
[someObject completeTaskWithCompletionHandler:^(NSString *result) {

}];
```

into a synchronous method that I can call like this:

```
NSString *result = [someObject completeTaskSynchronously];
```

How do I do this? I did some doc reading and internet search, and attempt to use "dispatch_semaphore" to do try to achieve it like so:

```
-(NSString *) completeTaskSynchronously {
   __block NSString *returnResult;
   self.semaphore = dispatch_semaphore_create(0);  
   [self completeTaskWithCompletionHandler:^(NSString *result) {
       resultResult = result;
       dispatch_semaphore_signal(self.semaphore);
   }];

   dispatch_semaphore_wait(self.semaphore, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER);
   return resultResult;
}
```

But this doesn't seem to work, it basically just halt at dispatch_semaphore_wait. Execution never reaches inside block that do the _signal. Anyone has code example on how to do this? I suspect that the block has to be on a different thread other the main thread? Also, assume I don't have access to the source code behind the async method.

Comment: If completion handler is executed on the same thread that calls dispatch_semaphore_wait you indeed deadlocked the thread because the completion block cannot be executed until the thread exits from the wait. Are you trying to do this on main thread? It is better to not block the main thread for long time because it must constantly dispatch messages.

Comment: If, as suspected by @yurish, you handler has been queued to the main dispatch thread, you must not wait.  You have to construct your code flow as a state-machine and do whatever needs to be done with result in the completion handler.

Comment: There is no general way to do this.  As others have said, if some part of the asynchronous task works by putting events on the run loop, you will always deadlock.  What are you *really* trying to achieve?  Maybe there's another way to structure your code.

Comment: @JeremyP The `[NSRunLoop -runMode:beforeDate:]` pattern is a "general way to do this" and avoids deadlock.

Comment: @AaronBrager No. Polling the run loop only prevents the dead lock if the implementation of the wrapped asynchronous method uses the run loop to dispatch the completion block.

Comment: @AaronBrager if you can't see the way the asynchronous call is implemented, you can't see if it is done by posting events to the run loop or forking a thread.  If the asynchronously is done by posting to the run loop, you simply can't wait for it because that will be deadlock.  If it uses threads, you might be able to wait, but the implementation might still try to run the completion handler on your run loop which means it degenerates to the previous problem.

Comment: You're right.  I'll leave my incorrect comment so future viewers can see what you're responding to.  Thank you for correcting me.

Comment: Thanks for all the useful feedback. I have gotten it to work via NSRunLoop way. It seemed to be simplest way. I also understand why it got stuck at the _wait. the code in the block is being directed to run on main thread when i looked at the src. I raised this question 'cos i want to wrap this method and make it available as synchronous version. it may ve use case in non-UI app, or for unit testing.

Answer (score 9):

`dispatch_semaphore_wait` blocks the main queue in your example. You can dispatch the async task to a different queue:

```
__block NSString *returnResult;
dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_LOW, 0UL);
dispatch_async(queue,^{
     result = [someObject completeTaskSynchronously];
});
```

Or use some other system, like NSRunLoop:

```
   __block finished = NO;
   [self completeTaskWithCompletionHandler:^(NSString *result) {
       resultResult = result;
       finished = YES;
   }];
    while (!finished) {
        // wait 1 second for the task to finish (you are wasting time waiting here)
        [[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] runMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode beforeDate:[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:1]];
    }
```

Answer (score 6):

Using an NSRunLoop is the easiest to do here.

```
__block NSString* result = nil;
[self completeTaskWithCompletionHandler:^(NSString *resultstring) {
    result = resultstring;
}];
while (!result) {
    [[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] runMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode beforeDate:[NSDate distantFuture]];
}
```

Comment: Yes, i think this works well. I also found a class MTTestSemaphore on github that encapsulate this and make it more semaphore-like. Thanks.

Comment: I wonder how well does this interact with normal event processing? Things like Core Animation transactions etc.

Comment: This cannot work well. The run loop requires events to be processed in order to return. If there are no events, it will only return in the "distant future", that is *never*. Furthermore, the access to the pointer `result` is not thread safe. It's not guaranteed that a pointer is not zero AND fully initialized. And (possibly) a compiler may be allowed to optimize away access to the memory location and keep the pointer in a register which gets never updated.

Comment: @CouchDeveloper you are correct, that this is not thread safe. NSRunLoops never are. You could check for `[result count] > 0` to ensure an initialized object. I have used this solution a couple of times without issue though. Can you provide a good alternative? NSConditionLock, NSLock and dispatch_semaphore are kind of hard to use. You could also use an NSOperation to wrap the asynchronous call and then use `-[NSOperation waitUntilFinished]` to block execution of the current thread. This can also lead to a deadlock however.

Answer (score 1):

I think the better solution will be NSRunLoop as given below. It's simple and working fine.

```
- (NSString *)getValue {

    __block BOOL _completed = NO;
    __block NSString *mValue = nil;

    [self doSomethingWithCompletionHandler:^(id __nullable value, NSError * __nullable error) {
        mValue = value;
        _completed = YES;
    }];

    while (!_completed) {
        [[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] runMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode beforeDate:[NSDate distantFuture]];
    }

    return mValue;
}
```

Comment: This cannot work well. See [CouchDeveloper comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20604857/how-to-wrap-an-asynchronous-method-that-takes-a-block-and-turn-it-synchronous-in/20611134#comment30971519_20611134).

Answer (score -3):

You can try to use NSOperations for this doing your things asynchronously.