# Using Asynchronous method inside a method has a return type

Tags: ios, web

I was using NSURLProtocol to manipulate request made from the Webview. I was trying to convert the request from host to ip address, and then send it out. I put those logic inside

```
+ (NSURLRequest *)canonicalRequestForRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request{
        Here is an asynchronous method which gives a NSString by using a block. 
        I need to convert this NSString back to NSURLRequest, 
        so the webview can load the content. 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the answer, it put a wrapper method to make asynchronous method which makes it behave like a synchronous method and return values. It basically use a while loop to block the return.

[how to wrap an asynchronous method that takes a block and turn it synchronous in objective c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20604857/how-to-wrap-an-asynchronous-method-that-takes-a-block-and-turn-it-synchronous-in)

Answer (score 0):

you can use block parameter to return value in block, then load this request in completion handler block.

```
+ (void)canonicalRequestForRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request completionHandler:(void (^)(NSURLRequest *request))completionHandler {
//    Here is an asynchronous method which gives a NSString by using a block.
//    I need to convert this NSString back to NSURLRequest,
//    so the webview can load the content.


    // call completionHandler inside of asynchronous block
    completionHandler(returnRequest);
}
```

Comment: Since 
+ (NSURLRequest *)canonicalRequestForRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request: is method from abstract class NSURLProtocol, I dont't think this a solution.https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLProtocol_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSURLProtocol/canonicalRequestForRequest: